# How to display post subheadings on the top in the form of a list

Tags: wordpress

Ive created a blog on wordpress. Each article is divided into various paragraphs under proper sub headings. 
I want to show the list of the all the sub headings on top of the post in the form of a numbered or bulleted list. And on clicking these list items the reader should be able to jump to the relevant text section on the post.
For example if the blog is like this ->

```
**Plan features**
A paragraph on plan features .............. .................. ......... ...
.............................

**Plan Benefits**
Aparagraph on plan benefits ............... .............. ........... ............... ........... ............. ................

**PlanReview**
A paragraph on reviews of the plan ............. .............. ......... ............. ............. .............. ............. ............
```

Then on top of the post I want a list of all the three subheadings:

1. **Plan features**
2. **Plan Benefits**
3. **PlanReview**

Each one should be linked to the correct place in the document.

I have done this earlier with the help of a plugin but cannot remember it anymore. Can anyone help me to achieve the above task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for "Table of Content". Box that is commonly found on Wikipedia. There are many plugins available for listing Table of Content for page & post.

I am sharing a link below from Wordpress directory.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-table-of-contents/

Hope it will help.